# Cannot open a file through fopen()

Tags: c++, c, file-io

Im working on making a simulator with c++, for which I need to read files.

my directory looks something like this

```
proj
------>bin        #stores the executable
------>include    #stroes the external library includefiles
------>lib        #stores the lib files of the libraries
------>obj        #stores the .o files
------>src        #source files
makefile
```

my make file looks this

```
CC = g++
OUT = chip8
ODIR = ./obj
SDIR = ./src
OUTDIR = ./bin
IDIR = ./include
LDIR = ./lib
libs = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SDIR)/%.cpp,$(ODIR)/%.o,$(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.cpp))
vpath %.cpp $(SDIR):$(SDIR)/Chip8

$(ODIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) -c -I $(IDIR) -o $@ $^

$(OUTDIR)/% : $(wildcard obj/*.o)
    $(CC) -L $(LDIR) -o $@ $^ $(libs)

.PHONY : run

run :
    $(OUTDIR)/$(OUT)
```

these are my source files

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Chip8/RomFileReader.h"


int main(){

    RomReader romReader;

    if(romReader.OpenFile("picture.ch8") == -1){
        std::cout<<"could not open file !"<<std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    romReader.GetRom();

    uint8_t * rom = romReader.ReturnRom();
    int size = romReader.GetRomSize();

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        std::cout<<rom[i]<<std::endl;

    free(rom);

    romReader.FreeRom();
    romReader.CloseReader();

}
```

ReadRomFile.h

```
#pragma once 

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class RomReader{

private :

    FILE * m_Reader;
    uint8_t * m_Rom; 

public : 

    int OpenFile(const char * fileName);
    void GetRom();
    void FreeRom();
    uint8_t * ReturnRom();
    void CloseReader();
    int GetRomSize();

};
```

RomFileReader.cpp

```
#include "RomFileReader.h"

int RomReader :: OpenFile(const char * fileName){

    m_Reader = fopen(fileName,"rb");

    if(m_Reader == NULL){
        return -1;
    } else 
        return 1;

}

int RomReader :: GetRomSize(){
    
    int start = ftell(m_Reader);
    fseek(m_Reader,0,SEEK_END);
    int end = ftell(m_Reader);
    fseek(m_Reader,0,SEEK_SET);

    int size = end - size;

    return size;

}

void RomReader :: GetRom(){

    int size = GetRomSize();

    if(m_Rom == NULL){
        m_Rom = new uint8_t[size];
    }

    fread(m_Rom,1,size,m_Reader);

}

void RomReader :: FreeRom(){

    free(m_Rom);

}

uint8_t * RomReader :: ReturnRom(){

    return m_Rom;

}


void RomReader :: CloseReader(){

    fclose(m_Reader);

}
```

this is the error I'm getting

```
./bin/chip8
could not open file !      
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

I could use fstream but I'm more comfortable and confident in using FILE instead, I had done something similar in c and it worked without any issue.

I'm really not able to point at what is exactly not working.

my picture.ch8 is in the bin folder along with the executable, yet I get this error. What is it that I'm missing exactly?

Comment: The file needs to be in the current working directory, which apparently is where the `makefile` is.

Comment: You did not start the executable from inside bin? The CWD is different!?
Use `/bin/picture.ch8` instead.

Comment: i changed put the file in the working directory and I get this error make: *** [run] Error -1073741819

Comment: Well, at least that's progress (the file was opened). In hex, that error number is C0000005. You can read all about it by googling C0000005.

Comment: @MiniMik i changed used /bin/picture.ch8 but i still get the same error, I also tried to put the ch8 file in the working directory but I get a weird error make: *** [run] Error -1073741819. I'm guessing it may have something to do with junk value ? or something wrong with my pointers ?

Comment: @user3386109 I searched and it says buffer overrun, I'm guessing it's something to do with my memory allocation then?

Comment: I think the problem is `int size = end - size;`. You probably meant `end - start`

Comment: @user33896109 i thought so too, i changed it to size = end - start. but still get the error make: *** [run] Error -1073741819

Comment: You should use delete not free(m_Rom). You should always pair new/delete or malloc/free

Comment: @Ian4264 I did that but I am still stuck with the same error, I'm trying to find a tool that would help me check for memory leaks in the code, so I can find where exactly am I having this problem.

Comment: regarding: `int size = end - size;`   This should be: `int size = end - start +1;`  and the function: `ftell()` returns a  `long`, not a `int`

Comment: the prototype for `fread()` is `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`  Your compiler should have been outputting lots of warnings about the posted code.  Suggest, when compiling,  enabling the warnings then fixing those warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main is calling

```
romReader.FreeRom();
```

I think `m_Rom` is not NULL. So the memory get freed, so the memory exception getting fired?!?

Set it to NULL in a constructor of your class:

```
class RomReader {

...
public : 
  RomReader() { m_Rom = NULL; };
  ~RomReader() { if ( m_Rom != NULL ) delete [] m_Rom; };
...
}
```

Comment: i made a constructor that sets the m_Rom to NULL and the code runs but nothing happens. But no errors

Comment: Thanks a lot for fixing my problem, after a little bit of tinkering with the code it works like magic

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem you have is that `wildcard` expands to the files that exist when make reads the makefile.  So when you build with a clean tree (where the `obj` directory is empty), it expands to nothing, so nothing gets built.

The upshot is that `wildcard` cannot be usefully used with intermediate files generated as part of your build as they might not exist yet when you build.  It is only useful for finding *source* files.

You need instead something like

```
$(OUTDIR)/$(OUT): $(patsubst src/%.cpp, obj/%.o, $(wildcard src/*.cpp)) $(patsubst src/Chip8/%.cpp, obj/%.o, $(wildcard src/Chip8/*.cpp))
```

You also probably want to have your `run` target depend on the executable

```
run: $(OUTDIR)/$(OUT)
```

otherwise it will not (re)build it when you try to run.

Comment: ok, here is the thing, i run make obj/main.o, it builds a object file main.o, then i run make obj/RomFileReader.o it build the object file RomFileReader.o. I then link them. So technically I do have the object files in the obj folder so they are not empty. So what is the deal then ? and not to mention i have problem with file reading, my makefile does just fine. Infact when i tried creating a sdl window before and it worked flawlessly. But then again, I'm still going to try and see if this fixes my problem and if not its still something new I have learnt

Comment: UPDATE : it does not fix my problem